# using spread syntax with Mongoose Document after calling the .save method results in undefined keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql

I'm using a Mongoose/MongoDB and I'm getting some odd behaviour when I try to use the spread syntax to return values from a document after I call .save() on it.

```
// Npc is a Mongoose schema
const npc = new Npc({
        ...input,
        creator: userId
      });

const createdNpc = await npc.save();
```

I have tried using the spead operator, but the name and description keys do not exist.

```
return {
          ...createdNpc
          creator: userFromId(npc.creator)
}
```

however when I access those values directly they ARE defined

```
return {
          description: createdNpc.description,
          name: createdNpc.name,
          creator: userFromId(npc.creator)
        };
```

I've made sure that the spelling of description and name are correct. I've tried logging both `{...createdNpc}` and `{...createdNpc, description: createdNpc.description, name: createdNpc.name}`. In the logs I've confirmed that name and description are both not defined (the keys don't exist) inside of {...createdNpc}

I have also tried logging `createdNpc` and `{...createdNpc}` and have confirmed that they return different values.

here's createdNpc:

```
{
  _id: 5d8d5c7a04fc40483be74b3b,
  name: 'NPC Name',
  description: 'My Postman NPC',
  creator: 5d8d50e0b5c8a6317541d067,
  __v: 0
}
```

it doesn't actually look like a Mongoose Document at all. I would post the result of `{...createdNPC}` to show the difference but it's a huge code snippet and I don't want to clutter the question. I'm happy to provide it if it will help!

I'm still very new to MongoDB & Mongoose. Why would using the spread syntax on a Mongoose Document change its value?

I don't think this should be relevant to the question but just in case I'll also mention this is for a graphql resolver.

Comment: I bet the properties are on an internal prototype, rather than on the object itself, in which case spread won't copy them - examine via `console.dir` to tell for certain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because Mongoose uses getters for all of its attributes. Before you use the spread operator, call `createdNpc.toObject()` to get a normal Object.